# Mover elementos clickeados de una array a otro

Tags: array, angular, typescript, eventos, click

lo que quiero hacer es mover un elemento de un array a otro, pero solo los que seleccione el usuario y sin JQuery, estoy en Angular 4, les dejo mi código.**texto en negrita**

```
    <div class="create-cont-top-left">
          <h5 class="clrGrayBlack">Lista de campus:</h5>
          <div class="cont-text">
            <p *ngFor="let campus of campuses">{{campus}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div (click)="addItem()" class="font">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: green"></i>
            <a>Agregar</a>
          </div>

  addItem(){
    let _ = this;

    for (let i = 0; i < _.campuses.length; i++){
      console.log(_.campuses[i]);
      _.campusesAggregates.push(_.campuses[i]);
      delete _.campuses[i];
      console.log(_.campusesAggregates[i]);
    }

    // console.log(_.campusesAggregates[i]);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el *ngFor y pasar el index para obtener rapidamente el elemento.

Primero recorres en un ngFor

```
<p (click)="addItem(i,campus)" *ngFor="let campus of campuses; let i=index">
  {{campus}}
  <a class="cursor-pointer green">+</a>
</p>
```

Luego recibes en una función.

```
addItem(index:number,item:string){
  this.selected.unshift(item);
  this.campuses.splice(index,1);
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como pasar elementos de una vector a otro.

[Ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-list-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Pasa el campus a mover directamente por el método:

```
addItem(toMove: Campus): void {
  const index = this.campuses.findIndex((c: Campus) => c.key === toMove.key);
  this.campuses.splice(index, 1); // eliminamos el campus del array original
  this.campusesAggregates.push(toMove); // lo agregamos al array origen
}
```

Y en el HTML:

```
<div (click)="addItem(campus)" class="font">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: green"></i>
  <a>Agregar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No me funciono :C
Me dice que key no esta definida

Comment: @EduardoGarcía Donde dice key es el campo por donde debes buscar. Puede ser id, nombre, etc.